Risk of Delay in Tasks that require review or multiple approvals
I work within the IT Banking Industry as an IT project Manager , most of my projects follow the waterfall method , one of very risky areas where the plan get's delayed and tasks get dragged are design approvals.
ex: our EA are responsible to finalize the system design by taking input from the vendor and the application team , they will require some time to release the first draft of which get circulated to be approved or commented on by the Vendor , Application Team and then Information Security. let's say this task is planned for 8 business days here where things go haywire , the EA might take 5 days to circulate the first draft , then vendor takes another day to reveiw and approve then the application owner ,then the Information security Team might come with comments which I need a1nother 3 days to address.
how can I better plan a task owned by own person howver requires approvals from multiple people that might delay the  task. should I create SLA for each step on the way or ask the owner to push for it to be finalized within the time .
much appreciated for any assistance

In this scenario, as a PM, I'd offer the EA my "coordination" services.  I do not want to own the task; it still belongs to the EA.  I could, however, draft the email and coordinate the responses.  Some people are uncomfortable with prodding people for answers.  "Prodding" is a PM task, so they expect me to prod people.  By offering the coordination services to the EA, I can take the information provided by the EA, send a request for approval, and keep prodding until the response is received.  Any lack of response can be noted in daily standups and status updates.  This keeps the heat on, it shows the importance of the EA's task, and it assures the rest of the team that the PM is not going to take "no" for an answer.

You have two basic choices:

Time box each review and approval process, clearly state the project assumptions for incorporating feedback and rework, and the escalation procedures for handling delays and change requests that exceed planned slack.
Hammer out working agreements ahead of time to ensure that feedback is timely, and that changes that affect timelines or scope have a clearly defined process.

Absent one of these two approaches, you have too many variables and too many "unknown-unknowns" to commit to a rigid scope or timeline. You can certainly fix a deadline for "approved" or "rejected," but as soon as you introduce multi-party reviews or changes, which generally have knock-on effects, rigid plans generally fail. Avoid that by deciding ahead of time what constraints are flexible, and then clearly communicating what's flexible and what's not to everyone involved.
If Bob proposes something, Alice recommends one set of changes while Fred makes a different set of recommendations, and then Bob and Alice have to reconcile the changes before everyone re-reviews the whole thing then you will never get off the merry-go-round. In most cases this isn't really about SLAs or time management; this is more often about leveraging collaboration rather than sequential work to reduce unproductive loops or "tossing work over the wall" in an organizational game of hot-potato.
